# How do I check for a file to be finished downloading Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to figure out how to check if a download has been completed. Basically I want it to wait until the file is finished downloading then print: Download completed.

Here is my current code and what I am trying to do with it:

```
from  urllib import request

print("Are you sure you want to download the newest file? y/n")
answer = input()

while True:
    if answer == 'y':
        print("Downloading file...")
        downloading = True
        request.urlretrieve("FILE_URL", "FILE_NAME")
    elif answer == 'n':
         exit()
    else:
         print("That is not a valid answer, please answer with y/n.")
         answer = input()

#I need some sort of function here that checks if the file is still being 
#downloaded

when downloading == False:
    print("Download Completed.")
```

Comment: `while answer is not 'y' or 'n':` doesn't do what you think it does. See [How to test multiple variables against a value?](//stackoverflow.com/q/15112125). I'll edit that out because it's not relevant to the question.

Comment: It works though.

Comment: By coincidence, yes. Actually, I just broke your code... hold on... there we go.

Comment: You can edit my code? I was so confused lol, I went to edit it myself and it was different. I thought I clicked on a different question on accident.

Comment: Why don't you just use the os module to check if the file exists ? Or you can use selenium webdriver too.

Comment: @VineethSai Just because the file exists doesn't mean the download has finished.

Comment: Ah, Forgot about that temp file

Comment: That's the whole problem. When downloading a big file I need to know when its done. I posted a question earlier saying my code was not working but really the download had not finished yet and I wasted everyone's time. I need to know when it is safe to close the program and open the file.

Comment: Is it possible to move the tempfile somewhere else until it is finished downloading maybe?

Comment: There is no tempfile involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `urlretrieve` returns, the file has already finished downloading.

See the usage example from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve):

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> local_filename, headers = urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://python.org/')
>>> html = open(local_filename)
```

As can be seen, the file is opened immediately after the call to `urlretrieve`, as it was already created and the content was already written there.

Comment: So how do I implement this into my code? I need something that will change that 'downloading == True' to 'downloading == False'

Comment: @NeverEndingCycle The point is that you don't need any of that. *The download is already finished.* Add `print("Download Completed.")` after the `urlretrieve(...)` call and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the  `urllib.request.urlretrieve` `reporthook` option, you can monitor the progress of the download, especially useful with large files, like so:

```
import urllib.request

def Download_Progress(block_num, block_size, total_size):
    downloaded = block_num * block_size
    progress = int((downloaded/total_size)*100)
    print ("Download Progress",str(progress),"%")

url = "https://somesite/some.pdf"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'mycopy.pdf', reporthook=Download_Progress)
print ("Finished")
```

You can achieve something similar with the `requests` package as well.

```
import requests
url = "https://somesite/some.pdf"

#Get the headers of the remote file
h = requests.head(url, allow_redirects=True)

#Get the size of the file
total_size = int(h.headers.get('content-length'))

#Request the file download with stream set to True
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

#Open a local file for writing
localfile = open("mycopy.pdf", "wb")
chunks = 0

#Process the file as it arrives
for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=512):
    if chunk:
        chunks += 1
        downloaded = chunks * 512
        # An approximation as the chunks don't have to be 512 bytes
        progress = int((downloaded/total_size)*100)
        print ("Download Progress",str(progress),"%")
        localfile.write(chunk)
print("Finished")
```