# How to check if the file is completely downloaded in a folder using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, python-watchdog

I am working on a python script that is responsible to organize your download folder, by arranging each type of file in a separate folder. I am using watchdog to check for modification in the download folder. If anything starts downloading the script runs although I want to wait till the download is complete before I run my script.

I cannot figure out how to check if downloading file is completely downloading using python.

I have included the code to show how my script basically works.

```
class ShiftingFiles(FileSystemEventHandler):
"""
This class is going to allow us to override the FileSystemEventHandler
methods.
"""
# Overriding the on_modified() method of FileSystemEventHandler class
# in the watchdog API
def on_modified(self, event):
    self.shift()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    # To shift the files as soon as the program is run
    ShiftingFiles().shift()
    # Consuming watchdog API
    event_handler = ShiftingFiles()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, download_location, recursive=False)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1000)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the intro tour.

Comment: Add some your stuff code, so users can help easily

Comment: Check out [How do I check for a file to be finished downloading Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52070906/how-do-i-check-for-a-file-to-be-finished-downloading-python3)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and this worked out for me. Wait that the transfer of the file is finished before processing it:

```
def on_modified(self, event):
        file_size = -1
        while file_size != os.path.getsize(event.src_path):
            file_size = os.path.getsize(event.src_path)
            time.sleep(1)

        self.shift()
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the better solution I think, but you can see last modification date at 1 minute interval, and if it's the same, consider that the file is completed.

Comment: That makes sense I'll try that !

Comment: I am not sure with how I can use that to determine if the file is already downloaded @Todd. I am not using python to download anything. The downloading is done by using the browser. I just want to see when it is downloaded completely.