# Python - Check if Download is Complete

Tags: python, python-3.x, download, python-multithreading, python-watchdog

I'm using a watchdog to monitor my downloads and move them somewhere else. However, when downloads are large and `shutil.move` is called before the download is completed, the destination file is incomplete or empty and the source file is not removed. As you can see, I've tried simply waiting, but for large downloads it's impossible to know how long I would have to wait and oftentimes the timer expires too soon.

```py
class DownloadHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    
    def on_created(self, event):
        if event.src_path.endswith(".zip"):
            thread.start_new_thread(move_file, (event.src_path, dst))


def move_file(src, dst):
    time.sleep(1)
    shutil.move(src, dst)
```

I've also tried implementing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60742521/13471744), but it still fails for large downloads (probably because my browser's downloader doesn't flush the download buffer until it is complete). Is there a reliable way to check if the download is complete in Python?

Comment: How is your program supposed to know if a download is complete?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Sorry if it wasn't clear. That is exactly my question.

Comment: If a file is actively downloading, its size should change. You could try to wait until the size does not change anymore.

Comment: @Baumkuchen That is exactly the suggestion in the linked answer, however as stated I did not have success with it.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the comment, what I meant was not simply waiting, but actively checking the size for changes, i.e.

```py
def move_file(src, dst):
    last_size = Path(src).stat().st_size
    time.sleep(1)
    while (current_size := Path(src).stat().st_size) != last_size:
        time.sleep(1)
        last_size = current_size
    shutil.move(src, dst)
```

Alternatively, you could try to check if the program, that you use for downloading, has still opened the file (see https://superuser.com/questions/97844/how-can-i-determine-what-process-has-a-file-open-in-linux).